# Chaining on an Array.find() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting into the habit of, depending on the context, converting some of my `for loops` to use `array.find()`. In so doing, I'm wondering if there's a way I can chain another operator on after the `.find()` in order to limit how much I grab from the object.

For instance, see the following:

```
currentStage = customerDoc.history.find(h => h.completed === false);
currentStageName = currentStage.name;
```

Since all I really want from here is the value for "currentStage.name", is there a way I can get this by chaining on after my `find()`, to specify I just want this property? If not, is there another way to do this in one line?

Comment: `.find(...).name`

Comment: @epascarello As much as I agree, an exception would be thrown if `find()` doesn't find anything.

Comment: @zero298 just like how it would with the code above ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can like this, notice the use of `|| {}` to avoid exception in case the find returns undefined

```
currentStage = (customerDoc.history.find(h => h.completed === false) || {}).name
```

But IMO you should keep it like you have right now, it's readable and easy to maintain

```
currentStage = customerDoc.history.find(h => h.completed === false);
currentStageName = currentStage && currentStage.name;
```

Comment: Given that .find returns *undefined* if it can't match anything, it would be good to ensure that `currentStage` is not undefined. This can be as simple as `currentStageName = currentStage && currentStage.name;`

Comment: Thanks, and yes, that's a fair point. Sometimes clarity beats out being hyper-terse.

Answer (score 4):

You could use optional chaining (which is currently a stage 3 TC39 proposal and not yet implemented in browsers) but can be used right now using [babel's](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) plugin and use it as such :

```
const currentStageName = customerDoc.history.find(h => !h.completed)?.name;
```

Comment: In JS `?.` operator exists?

Comment: It's a stage 3 proposal in TC39 https://tc39.es/proposal-optional-chaining/

Comment: In order to use this, you would need to run it through [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining). Best I could find, no browsers currently support optional chaining.

Answer (score 3):

Use [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) to have a default object in case nothing if found, and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) to get the property you want. If nothing is found, the result would be `undefined`:

```
const { name: currentStageName } = customerDoc.history.find(h => h.completed === false) || {};
```

Comment: I like the destructuring method better because it keeps it all on one line, the disadvantage is makes for a longer and more complex line of code.

Answer (score 1):

you could also chain a .map onto the find results in order to limit and/or reshape what gets returned by wrapping it in an array (and using filter if no results are found), e.g.

```
currentStage = [customerDoc.history.find(h => h.completed === false)].filter(h => h != undefined).map(h => ({'name':h.name}))[0]
```